# Best Practice for the Structure of a Big Pallet

Tags: pallet, substrate-node

My pallet has over 1,000 lines of codes so far(already separated implementation of the call functions).
Over 30 call functions which are pretty messy to maintain.

Should I split them into small pallets and couple them all together?
Should I split the test file and benchmarking as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to take a look at some of the [FRAME pallets](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame).
The [balances pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/README.md) is a good example, it has the test file, benchmarking, types and different traits implementations in their own files.

Take a look into the [nfts-pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/nfts/README.md), it has more than 30 call functions too, and another example of a even bigger pallet is the [staking pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/README.md), where it splits some logic in their own pallets.

Also I'd like to share with you another interesting resources:

- [General coding practices from Substrate docs](https://docs.substrate.io/build/troubleshoot-your-code/).
- A workshop that was prepared for a hackathon: [Best Practices in Building Substrate Pallets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBEcgKJseTc)

That's a good question, I'd love to see other answers with more feedback about best practices building a pallet.